# How do you prove $\lvert x - y \rvert < 1$ then $\lvert x\rvert<\lvert y\rvert +1 $?

Tags: analysis, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

> How do you prove $\lvert x - y \rvert < 1$ then $\lvert x\rvert<\lvert y\rvert +1 $?

I know this proof has the form of the triangle inequality, but I can't seem to figure it out. This is from Kenneth Ross 17.1

Comment: Now your title and question are different.

Comment: Oh, I thought the title was a reformulation of the original textbook question

Comment: It might be, but that's not clear to me.  That might be my problem.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I was being helpful by reducing it but I went about it wrong.

Comment: $\lvert x\rvert - \rvert y \rvert\le\lvert x - y \rvert < 1\implies\lvert x\rvert<\lvert y\rvert +1$

Comment: In mathematics if you want to state the hypothesis that statement A implies statement B, we write something like "**If** A, **then** B" or else something like "A **⇒** B".

Answer (score 4):

$|x| = |x-y+y| \leq |x-y|+|y|\stackrel{|x-y|<1}{\implies} |x| < 1+|y|$

More generally, this trick shows $|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|$ and by symmetry, $|y|-|x|\leq |x-y|$ and therefore, $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ which is a common way to prove that absolute value is a (uniformly) continuous function.

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thank you

Comment: @nnabahi, it's a common trick, worth to remember. You are welcome.

Comment: @nnabahi you can accept the answer that you think best answers your question by ticking a check mark on the left side of the answer. This awards reputation points to the person who answered you, but even more importantly, removes your question from unanswered section of the site.